# Why can't I telnet to MySQL?

Tags: server, mysql, connection, telnet

When trying to connect to mysql server via telnet I am getting following error:

```
telnet localhost 3306
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

I tried telnet with 127.0.0.1, `hostname` also, but getting same error message. But I can connect with `mysql -u username -p` once I am in the server.

Here is the result of netstat:

```
netstat -na | grep mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4540495  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     4542200  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

netstat -na | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

What could be possible problems? If you need some more details I could provide it without any problems.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL uses the UNIX socket on localhost - much faster. It won't run on a TCP port unless you tell it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your `iptables` settings?

```
sudo iptables -L -v
```

Comment: I have disabled firewall temporarily with "sudo ufw disable". Does it stop iptables also?

Comment: @Bakhtior yes: `ufw` is a simplified frontend to `iptables`.

Comment: So, why I am not able to telnet to mysql then?

Comment: @Bakhtiyor Just a clarification: you say "When trying to connect to the MySQL server I get this error ..." and then "I can connect via ... _once I'm in the server"_  Does this mean that you're trying the `telnet localhost` command on a host which is _not_ the MySQL server host?

Comment: First I am connecting to the server with ssh, and then right from the server I am executing telnet command.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor ...and you've shut down the firewall on the _server,_ right?

Comment: Yes, right in the server I am disabling ufw.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor Sorry, then I have no clue what's happening. I'll leave the answer hanging here as the comments might provide info for someone who knows.

Comment: All right @Riccardo, thx a lot for trying to help me.